# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null in Google Chrome 's Console

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I used that **jquery-1.9.1.min.js** and **bootstrap-table**,that code is:

```js
    function operationFormatter(value,row) {
            var  bt = "<button class='btn btn-info' 
            onclick='open(\""+value+"\")' >show</button>";
            console.log(value)
            if(row.isopen==1){
                bt = "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='close(\""+value+"\")' >hiddeen</button>";
            }
            console.log(bt);
            return bt;
        }

  function open(id) {
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            url: '${ctx}/backstage/openUserQuestion?id='+id,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    $('#questionErrorList').bootstrapTable('remove', {
                        field: 'id',
                        values: [parseInt(id)]
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

that stateFormatter is the bootstrap-table's columns[].formatter

Comment: your question title and provide code is not complimenting to each-other. Please provide full code(jQuery+html+library too) and describe your problem by pointing out where you got stuck and what exact error you got? (As i am not able to see any `contains` like thing in your given code)

Comment: missing to close single quotes ss = 'hiddeen';

Comment: I'm sorry。My english is not very good。This problem is has solved。I changed that Function name to others. The cause of this issue is that  onclick=‘open(\""+value+"\")’ ,the function name is conflict to JQuery's inner Function。